# How to show another Dialog after primary authentication for step up authentication

Tags: c++, windows, credential-providers

Working on a cutom credential provider (CP). I want to show a dialog box to the user after a successful primary authentication. I am not sure how to achieve this - In which method to write the code to display the dialog box. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean "primary authentication" as windows logon?

Comment: @sailesh D Yes. First Windows authentication and then on success security questions kind of authentication